# Codecademy Practice Makes Perfect 10/15 (Word Censoring)

Tags: python

I'm on Codecademy, the section called "Practice Makes Perfect", on problem 10/15, the word-censoring one. The problem goes like this:

Write a function called `censor` that takes two strings, `text` and `word`, as input. It should return the text with the `word` you chose replaced with asterisks.

My idea was to do this:

```
def censor(text, word):
    length_of_word = len(word)
    word_now_censored = '*' * length_of_word
    wordlist = text.split()
    for item in wordlist:
        if item == word:
            item = word_now_censored
    return " ".join(wordlist)
```

But, so it seems, changing the value of `item` in the for loop doesn't change the value of the item in the list.

I thought another way could be to use a `while` loop, going from `i = 0` to `i < len(wordlist)`, and then modify `wordlist[i]` as needed, but I'd just like to understand why my `for`-loop method doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
for index, item in enumerate(wordlist):
    if item == word:
        wordlist[index] = word_now_censored
```

Comment: that looks really cool, could you please explain how you can have 2 words after for, before in?

Comment: `enumerate` is a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate). While iterating over a sequence, it allows you access to the current index of the item being accessed. You can use it like this: `for index, item in enumerate(["a", "b", "c"]): print index, item`, which will print `0 a 1 b 2 c`. As you can see, `0` corresponds to the index of the first element of list `["a", "b", "c"]`, `1` to the second, and so on.

Comment: @MaximedeMontbron If an answer solved your question, [you can _accept_ it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by checking the green checkmark left of the question. This signals to other users that this question has been answered satisfactorily and doesn't require additional answers. (Alternatively, if you feel your question has not been answered satisfactorily, please edit your question and specify what you feel is missing.) Choose the answer that you feel best helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply use `re.sub` to replace all instances of `word`:

```
import re

def censor(text, word):
    return re.sub(r'\b{}\b'.format(word), '*' * len(word), text)
```

Comment: This is the most Pythonic way in my opinion

Comment: This might replace things you don't really want to replace though. For example "grass", might become "gr***".

Answer (score 1):

Your observation is right

> changing the value of item in the for loop doesn't change the value of the item in the list.

There are many ways to go about this. Here is one way. Create another variable `new_words_list`. Append the word from `wordlist` to `new_words_list` if it not `word`. Else append `word_now_censored` to `new_words_list`.

Which translates to:

```
def censor(text, word):
    length_of_word = len(word)
    word_now_censored = '*' * length_of_word
    wordlist = text.split()
    new_words_list = []
    for item in wordlist:
        if item == word:
            new_words_list.append(word_now_censored)
        else:
            new_words_list.append(item)

    return " ".join(new_words_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def censor(text,word):
    text=list(text)

    for n in range(0,len(text)):
        i=0
        while 1==1:
            for i in range(0,len(word)):
                if  text[n+i]==word[i]:
                    i+=1
                else:             
                    break
            if i==len(word):
                for m in range(0,i):
                    text[n+m]='*'
            else:
                break
        n+=i
    return "".join(text)

print censor("this hack is wack hack", "hack")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version:

```
def censor(text, word):
    lst = text.split()
    while word in lst:
        index = lst.index(word)
        lst.remove(word)
        lst.insert(index,'*' * len(word))
    return " ".join(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

censor takes two strings, text and word, as input. It returns the text with the word you chose replaced with asterisks.

```
def censor(text,word):
    result = ""
    count = 0
    no_of_stars = 0
    split_list = text.split()
    for i in split_list:
        count += 1
        if(i==word):
            result += "*" * len(i)
        else:
            result +=i
        if(count != len(split_list)):
            result += " "    
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version. Simply build a new word of asterisks the same length as the word, then replace it.

```
def censor(text, word):
if word in text:
    blabber = ""
    while True:
        blabber += "*"
        if len(blabber) == len(word):
            break
    return text.replace(word, blabber)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def censor(text,word):
res = text.split()
temp = ""
for i,j in enumerate(res):
    if j == word:
        res[i] = "*" * len(word)
return " ".join(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it and this was my solution:

```
def censor(text, word):
   textList = text.split()

   for index, var in enumerate(textList):
       if var == word:
          textList[index] = "*" * len(word)

   return " ".join(textList)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def censor(text,word) :
    c=''
    for i in text.split() : 
        if i == word : 
             i = "*" * len(word)
             c += ' ' + i
        else :
            c += ' ' + i
    return c       


print censor("this hack is wack hack", "hack")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def censor(text, word):
lista=[]
for i in text.split():
    if i==word:
        lista+=['*'*len(word)]
    else:
        lista+=[i]
return ' '.join(lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def censor(text, word):
    new_text = text.split()
    ctext = []
    for item in new_text:
        if item == word:
            item = "*" *len(word)
        ctext.append(item)
    return " ".join(ctext)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def censor(text, word):
    a = word
    b = len(a)
    for a in text:
        text = text.replace(word, "*"*b)
    return text
```

Comment: _While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so._

Answer (score 0):

My idea was just:

```
def censor(text, word):
    answer = text.replace(word, "*"*len(word))
    return answer
```

This is might be simple one but I think simple is good. And I didn't have to use any loop, is it good?
If you like my answer, please let me know, I'll be really happy. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've made it quite simple and I don't see why no one mentioned this.

```
def censor(text, word):
    return text.replace(word,"*" * len(word))
```

Comment: I believe it is because if you call `censor("word or words", "or")`, you should get `"word ** words"`, not `"w**d ** w**ds"`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll appreciate it if you will take a look at this one.

```
def censor(text, word):
    if word in text:
        return text.replace(word, '*' * len(word))
```